# German characters are not supported in xml and Notepad++

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, notepad++

I am writing some text into .xml files, the data includes some German characters (ex: äöüß ) also, but if I write German characters into xml, I am not able to open that xml file in browser( tried with I.E, F.F) and if I open that file in Notepad++, I have seen some hex values in place of German characters.
I have tried by changing Encoding options in Notepad++ but there is no change still I see hex values only.

I am using UTF-8 encoding while writing data into xml as below.

and

(o/p in notepad++ in place of äöüß  characters can see some weird chara).

how to get over this, how can I see my German characters in Notepad++ andI want to open them in browsers.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your Notepad++ encoding setting. I see these characters properly and my setting is "Encode in UTF-8".

Comment: my notepad++ setting is Encoded to UTF-8 .

Comment: I copied the German characters from your question and pasted in my notepad++ and i do see them properly. If you observe the same behavior, can you share a unit xml file in case something is different with a file?

Comment: hi thanks for the effort, now I am able to see the characters. while I am writing I have used encoding=UTF-8, if change the encoding to UTF-16 or windows-1252, it working fine and I am able to see all the German characters in both browser and notepad.